# Null values are inserted after synchronize using Microsoft synch framework 2.1

Tags: frameworks, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am using Microsoft Synchronization Framework 2.1 and when I perform Synchronize, null values are inserted rather actual data. Can anyone please suggest me the approach in solving this issue.